# Jenkins Html reports threshold

Tags: jenkins

I am looking for Jenkins plugin that will help to add threshold on generated Html reports failures. Could someone please help? 
If no such plugin is available,  any other workaround  please?

Comment: what kind of reports? reports that your build generates? or reports about tests cases by junit ?  ....

Comment: Reports that build generates.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jenkins [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin), HtmlPublisher plugin is useful to publish the html reports that your build generates to the job and build pages. Below are the steps to publish and archive the HTML report files

Plugin ID htmlpublisher
Latest Release 1.11
Latest Release Feb 04, 2016 
Required Core 1.580.1